# Cast boost::units type into numeric types

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++11

I am using the `boost::units` library. My problem is that I have to cast my length vector into a double vector for a cmath calculation:

```
  pow(tmpVector.at(cnt),cnt)
```

cnt is my loop counter. If I try the calculation without casting I revive the error that there is no casting definition for `boost::units::length` into `double`.

I tried to use static_cast which don't work and numeric_cast of the boost library which also doesn't work. In the second case I receive the following compiler error:

```
e:\testvs12\libraries\thirdparty\boost\boost\numeric\conversion\converter_policies.hpp(187): error C2440: 'static_cast': 'const std::vector<_Ty>' can not convert into 'std::vector<_Ty>'
```

I found nothing in the internet - I hope one of you can help me

Question 1: is there a possibility to use pow inside a loop with `boost::units` and the loop counter as exponent?

Question 2: how can I cast a `boost::units` type into e.g. a double?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you providen an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org), please? I assume you don't have a vector of `length` but a vector of `quantity<length>`? Did you try dividing by `meter`, `feet` or whatever unit you want to be used? 1 meter converted to double could be `100.0` (i cm), `39.3701` (inches) or something else.

Comment: Is this ? tmpVector.at(cnt).value()  http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_37_0/doc/html/boost/units/quantity.html#id3387713-bb

Comment: sorry, yes i use a vector of quantity<length>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The canonical way to turn a value with units into a scalar is to divide by one unit of the measure as suggested by Arne Mertz in the comments.  In other words, something like:

```
 pow(tmpVector.at(cnt)/boost::units::meters,cnt)
```

Should work.